# executeQuery() and getResultSet() when retrieving data from callable statement

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

Is there a difference between calling `.execute`, `.getResultSet` and `.executeQuery` when getting the result set from a stored procedure that has no input and output parameters in JDBC?

Comment: execute() is used in conjunction with getResultSet and getmoreResults to retrieve one or more result sets. The boolean signifies if there was a result set. executeQuery() returns a single result set, and throws an exception if none was generated by the statement. I would think you would use execute() for dynamic SQL, and executeQuery() when you know you will be getting a result set back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute` returns just boolean value and to get result set or updates count, you have to explicitly call those methods

when you use `executeQuery`or `executeUpdate` directly, you're skipping one step (useful in basic operations when you know what will be returned to you as SQL result).

Comment: So suppose the stored proc is just "select * from table", it's best to just use callableStatement.executeQuery() because the stored proc returns the result from the select statement?

Comment: Yes and no. Even `UPDATE table SET column=value` returns some result. What we are interested in is type of the result. 

In destructive operations (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT), database will return you number of rows affected. = use `executeUpdate()`.

In "nothing-will-be-changed" operations (SELECT), database will return you matching result set = use `executeQuery()`.

Comment: Ok, so we can say, .execute() returns boolean value, .executeUpdate() returns number of rows affected (I would think select statement will result in 0) and .executeQuery() returns the resultSet if you want the result set and the query is non destructive. but all of them execute the queries in statement, preparedStatement and callableStatement they mostly differ in return values. Is that right?