# ExecuteQuery() vs getResultSet() in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

What is the difference between `statement.executeQuery` and `statement.getResultSet()`. I believe both will return `ResultSet` for a select statement but are there any specific criteria when we should use which of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [executeQuery() and getResultSet() when retrieving data from callable statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212592/executequery-and-getresultset-when-retrieving-data-from-callable-statement)

Comment: @EmreAcar  The possible duplicate answers the difference between execute, executeUpdate and executeQuery. I am more interested in the difference between executeQuery and getResultSet as both return the same thing (a resultSet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general you should use `executeQuery` if you know you are executing a select statement. The `getResultSet()` method by itself **does not execute the statement**.

The `getResultSet` is intended to be used in combination with `execute`. The `execute` methods are intended for use with unknown statement types, or statements that can produce multiple results (that is 0 or more update counts or result sets).

So in short: you should normally use `executeQuery`.

A simple example when you should use `execute` if the code doesn't know what query it is going to execute (an update, a query, or something more complex), for example when executing user provided queries.

Another example are SQL Server stored procedures, which can return multiple update counts and result sets.

A generic way of processing a result of `execute` is:

```
boolean isResultSet = statement.execute(sql);
while (true) {
    if (isResultSet) {
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet()) {
            // do something with result set
        }
    } else {
        int updateCount = statement.getUpdateCount();
        if (updateCount == -1) {
            // -1 signals no more results
            break;
        }
        // do something with update count
    }
    // move to next result
    isResultSet = statement.getMoreResults();
}
```

This ensures that all<sup>*</sup> results get processed.

<sup>*: This example ignores exception results for systems (like SQL Server) that allow multiple exceptions to be interleaved with result sets and update counts, see [How to get *everything* back from a stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169951/how-to-get-everything-back-from-a-stored-procedure-using-jdbc) for a more thorough example</sup>

Comment: Thanks Mark. If you can add any performance related differences (if any), it would be very helpful.

Comment: @PratikKumawat There is unlikely to be a performance difference, but that would depend on the specific driver implementation, so can't be answered with 100% certainty in general. Just keep it simple and use `executeQuery()` unless your really have to do something else.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But your code confused me a bit. Are statement and stmt different? Is there any max value which is returned by getResultSet()? If not then why did you use stmt.getMoreResults();

Comment: @PratikKumawat No, that was me unconsciously switching between variables names in my code, I have fixed this.

Comment: @PratikKumawat This has nothing to do with a 'max value' of a result set (there is no such thing). The point of this processing is that there can be an arbitrary number of update counts and result sets (in arbitrary order). If you want to process all these results, this is what you need to do. The most common example I know are SQL Server stored procedures, which can produce multiple update counts and multiple result sets from a single stored procedure call. For example a SP that does a select, an update and another select produces a result set, an update count and another result set.

Comment: @PratikKumawat - Related question: [How to get *everything* back from a stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42169951/2144390)

Answer (score -2):

Check out the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) for these methods. `getResultSet` can return null but `executeQuery` never return null.

There are also more constraints. For example `executeQuery` cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Is there any difference from performance perspective? I have gone through the JavaDoc but that didnt help much.