# How to check if an SQL statement is a query or an update?

Tags: java, mysql

I'd like to check if an SQL statement is a query or an update/insert/delete before I actually execute the statement. Right now I'm doing this:

```
if (stmt.execute(sqlStatement)) {
    // Deal with queries
}
else {
    // Deal with updates/inserts/deletes
}
```

where stmt is a Java Statement.

The problem is that I need to perform some SQL logic only before updates/inserts/deletes to the table but not before queries.

Comment: a select gives you back a resultset all the other the number of effeced row. so you have always to check if it a selected to handle the reply

Comment: Red flag.  You should not need to check, because you should already know.  The fact that you don't implies that you may be doing something questionable... and the lack of any parameters also seems suspicous.  In the interest of security and best practices, you may eant to explain why your code does not already know what kind of query is being attempted here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It's for a project where the user enters sql commands through a jsp frontend which is processed on the server side. When a certain variable is greater than 100 in the table, the business logic should update a few things in a separate table. I needed to know what kind of statement it was beforehand so I could create a temporary table only when the statement was an update. I ended up just creating a temporary table no matter what and dropping it when the business logic finished.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Something like:

   if (sqlStatement.stripLeading().toLowerCase()startsWith("select")) { 
         // deal with queries
     } else { // assume it's something else
     }
2. Alternatively, JDBC has a [getResultSet()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52700573/783412) method that is intended to be used following execute, so your code will then be:

   // deal with query preparation
    ResultSet results = jdbcStmtObj.getResultSet();
    if (results != null) { // we have results
    }

Comment: I think I'll have to use the first option but instead use if (!(sqlStatement.stripLeading().toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) since I need to deal with the cases that aren't selects. The second option would require that I execute the statement first which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: They're presented to give you the choice, matey.

Comment: A query that returns rows may also start with `WITH..` for a CTE.

Comment: If it's EXEC, you won't be able to tell from the query text whether it's returning rows or not.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if I'm reading your question correctly, I [think you can](https://www.boraji.com/jdbc-callablestatement-resultset-example).

Comment: No, not without running it.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is contained in a php string... can't you use the php function strpos() to look for the operative word... then branch or execute your If statement based on that.